# Translating multiple default variables from Chef to Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

How would a node attribute being set by a case in Chef be translated to a variable in Ansible?

Example:

```
case node['custom_attribute']
when 'security_standard_1'
  security_standard = 'ss1'
when 'security_standard_2'
  security_standard = 'ss2'
else
  security_standard = 'off'
end
```

I've only seen things that have two possible values being set with jinja.

```
security_standard: "{{ security_standard_1 | security_standard_2 }}"
```

Is this thought process even doable in Ansible?

Comment: You basically have yaml files with variable values, and the name of the yaml syncs with some attribute associated with a fact, like `Linux.yaml` and `Windows.yaml`. This is kind of a broad question to give an example for, but you get the idea.

Comment: See accepted answer below for how to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define variables using jinja template with if-else conditions to suit your needs.

Here's an example:

```
security_standard: "{%- if (security_standard_1 is defined) -%}ss1
                    {%- elif (security_standard_2 is defined) -%}ss2
                    {%- else -%}off
                    {%- endif -%}"
```

Comment: I can also do `custom_attribute == 'security_standard_1` and have it operate off of that.